# Terraform - cloud run multiple environment variables from list

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set multiple environment variables on a cloud run module I've created. The example I'm following from Terraform is static. Is it possible to dynamically create these?

```
template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
        env {
          name = "SOURCE"
          value = "remote"
        }
        env {
          name = "TARGET"
          value = "home"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#example-usage---cloud-run-service-multiple-environment-variables

I've tried:

```
dynamic "env" {
   for_each = var.envs
   content {
     name  = each.key
     value = each.value
   }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in
> │ its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.

Edit: Full code example

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-srv"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
        env {
          name = "SOURCE"
          value = "remote"
        }
        env {
          name = "TARGET"
          value = "home"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
  autogenerate_revision_name = true
}
```

Comment: Do you have complete example where `template` is used along with `env`?

Comment: It's exactly the same as the example in the link, but I'll update to give a full view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use dynamic blocks, you **can't use `each`**. It should be:

```
dynamic "env" {
   for_each = var.envs
   content {
     name  = env.key
     value = env.value
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll give this a go and follow up

Comment: @Ari No problem. Please let me know how did it go.

Comment: Where do you put this `dynamic` block? Inside the `google_cloud_run_service` somehow?

Comment: @1252748 Please make new question specific to your issue with your code.

Comment: It's literally the same question, just asking you to provide more context.